# How can I see the source of built-in JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, built-in, javascript-engine

E.g., alert(), Object(), String(), etc. How would I see the code behind these functions?

Would I need to understand the language that an engine, such as [V8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29), is written in and read through that, or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: See [How to get native javascript functions source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22371251/1048572)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> How would I see the code behind these functions?

You would need to find the source code for the relevant project (Firefox, Chromium, V8, SpiderMonkey, etc.), provided the project is open-source.

> Would I need to understand the language that an engine such as V8 is written in and read through that, or is there a simpler solution.

Yes, you would. Note that `alert` is not a JavaScript function, it's a function defined by web browsers (so you'd need to look at the Firefox or Chromium, etc., source). `Object` and `String` are both part of JavaScript, so you'd look at the JavaScript engine sources for those (SpiderMonkey [or *whatever*Monkey, the prefix seems to change a lot] and V8, etc.).