# Source code of implementation JavaScript internal methods

Tags: javascript, language-implementation

Is there a way to see the code behind a JavaScript's method? Not a javascript method from the website's .html or .js files, but JavaScript's internal methods.

For example:

- How can I see how JavaScript calculates the `offsetTop` of an element?

Comment: It's browser dependent. Also some browsers might not even use JavaScript for its internal calculations.

Comment: For example of I want to see with chrome?

Comment: See also [How to see the source of Built-in javascript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22300206/1048572)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> JavaScript is implemented by the browser, so **it depends on the browser**.

**Google's browser, `Chrome`**, is [closed-source not open-source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_and_closed-source_software). Which means that you ***can't*** view their source code, including their implementation of JavaScript. **But**, Chrome's source code is based on **Chromium**'s source code, which ***is*** open source. You can view all of its source code in its [git repository here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git). See more about this Chrome-Chromium relationship at the bottom of my answer.

**Mozilla's browser, `Firefox`**, is open-source just like all of their projects. You can view all of the source code for Mozilla projects [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Viewing_and_searching_Mozilla_source_code_online). You'll find the code that implements JavaScript in Firefox [right here](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/js).

For closed-source implementations of JavaScript, like Chrome's, you can never be **sure** exactly how each method works. By reading the documentation available (see below), you will be able to get the ***best*** available idea of how a method might be implemented.

**Note** that just because **Chrome**'s source code is based off of the open source project, **Chromium**, that doesn't mean the source code is the ***same***. Chrome could have made tweaks to to JavaScript methods, and we wouldn't know. I think that is unlikely though, and all of the differences between Chrome and Chromium are most likely listed [on this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_%28web_browser%29#Differences_from_Google_Chrome), and a nice post is available [here on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6253/whats-the-difference-between-google-chrome-and-or-chromium-what-are-the-advant)

You can learn a lot more about Chromium's source code [here](https://www.chromium.org/Home).

[Chrome JS documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index)

---

Comment: Thank you so much:):)An other quastion:the code behind javascript method is equal to normal code of javascript or it has a different implementation?

Comment: @Fistright Remember to upvote answers that help you, and mark an answer as `the answer` if you think it answered your question!

Comment: @Fistright I'm not sure I understand what you're asking in the comment. Could you rephrase the question?

Comment: If for example I see the code behind scrollTop () method it is normal javascript? could someone reproduce it with normal javascript?

Comment: Yes, it's just regular javascript. It's the exact same as writing the method yourself and placing it in `<script>` tags in your `.HTML` files.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce ScrollTop method but I have no ideas?Do you know how this method is implemented?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt: Your answer is misleading. Chrome is a slightly tweaked Chromium, which is [entirely open source](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code).

Comment: @Blender Thanks, I'm about to edit my answer to represent this fact. I'll also do some research and add what I find.

Comment: @Fistright Have you searched the mozilla or chromium docs for this function?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt: Can you name a single difference between how Chrome and Chromium render pages or execute JavaScript? I don't think it's fair to say that Chrome "could" be doing something different just because it's closed source.

Comment: Yes but I haven't found it:(

Comment: @Blender I don't think there is a single difference. And I state that by saying that I think it is unlikely Chrome has changed any javascript code from Chromium. But I can't without hard evidence, say that it is ***absolutely certain*** that Chrome hasn't changed any javascript code from the Chromium project.

Comment: @Fistright I'll have a look and see what I can find for it.

Comment: You're trying to reproduce `scrollTop`, why not just use it?

Comment: @Fistright It looks like `scrollTop` isn't a Javascript method, rather it's simply an attribute of HTML elements. Read [this page on Element.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop).

Comment: So it seems that javascript method just show us the value of this attribute.It is like padding or margin...no?

Comment: @Fistright What JavaScript method? There isn't a JavaScript method for scrollTop. But, just like any attribute on an html element, you can access and modify it in JavaScript code with `.scrollTop`

Comment: And what is the difference between scrolltop property and margin of an element:)I am a little bit confused:):)

Comment: @Fistright You can change scrollTop, and it will affect the scrolling distance. You can not change margin.

Comment: So scroll top is a property of an element and JavaScript doesn't calcolate it but  allow us to show it and modify it...right?