# How do libraries/programming languages convert floats to strings

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, type-conversion, programming-languages

This is a mystery that I was trying to figure out when I was 15, but I failed. I still don't know the answer.

Here's a naive and flawed solution (like some other failed attempts I've seen here on Stack Overflow):

```
const numberToString = number => {
  let result = '';
  let multiplier = Math.floor(Math.log10(number));
  while (number > 0) {
    const currentDigit = Math.floor(number / 10 ** multiplier);
    if (multiplier === -1) result += '.';
    result += `${currentDigit}`;
    number -= 10 ** multiplier * currentDigit;
    multiplier -= 1;
  }

  if (multiplier >= 0) {
    result += Array(multiplier + 1)
      .fill('0')
      .join('');
  }
  return result;
};

numberToString(0.3) //.29999999999999998010382707025852380980776467160900842259699366886095386217478302201335914442574948883370288946713085380211028267974348864228883494754227105763273602317743416839701366257194448416238466245093684421946526875873398794558223163136792877759774069929483218021428696258138483228158055137040848084556063610493291767
```

The language here is in Javascript, but the question is language agnostic. However, feel free to improve the existing code if it's possible.

If the way this works is language dependent, I would appreciate some insights how this might look in various programming languages, for example Javascript.

Comment: It's difficult to treat this question as language agnostic since each language treats numbers a little differently.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have clarified my question

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type) out? It defines the behavior of what Number.toString() should be.

Comment: And it should be noted that the toString() function in JavaScript is probably written in C++ and depends on your browser implementation. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300206/how-to-see-the-source-of-built-in-javascript-functions)

Comment: That specification specifies a number known as being "the number of digits in the decimal representation of s", but not how to algorithmically arrive there. Or am I missing something? What I'm searching for is an algorithm on how to get the answer, and I would presume that there should be a standard way of doing this, that the browsers all do it in a similar way

Comment: I just thought it was interesting and relevant to your question. By itself, it doesn't answer your question so I put it as a comment.

Comment: Note: `float` is datatype in many languages, which most often refers to IEEE-754 single-precision floating-point format (aka Single). JavaScript uses the IEEE-754 double-precision floating-point format (aka Double).

Comment: There is no simple solution. You can take a look at the classic `dtoa.c` written by David Gay ( also make sure you read his paper, https://ampl.com/REFS/rounding.pdf )

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have enough reputation to comment, so am resorting to using an answer...)

I notice that you ran the precision out to 300+ digits, well beyond the precision of the floating point numbers, hence the imprecise result.  If you're looking for a means to have high precision calculations, you can probably resort to BigInt, and scale up the numbers accordingly.  (I say "probably", because BigInt can be coerced into fixed precision calculations, not floating point, and thus depending on one's goal, BigInt might not meet the requirement.)

Eg, calculating 1000 / 17 to 100 significant digits can be handled via the following function, which essentially scales up 1000 and 17 to ensure 100 significant digits.  (Note that this is just a concept function for handling high precision division between two integers, but can be the basis for non-integers by scaling up the **dividend** and **divisor** until they're integers, and adjusting **digits** accordingly.  Plus you might need to fudge in some extra "hidden" digits of precision to handle rounding)...

```
function divideN(dividend, divisor, digits) {
  dividend = dividend * 10n ** (BigInt(digits) * 2n);
  divisor = divisor * 10n ** BigInt(digits);
  var s = (dividend/divisor).toString();
  if (s.length < digits) {
    s = "0".repeat(digits - s.length) + s;
  }
  s = s.slice(0, s.length - digits) + "." + s.slice(-digits);
  return s;
}
```

BigInt requires numbers to end in "n", so the function needs to be called as follows...

```
divideN(1000n,17n,100)
```

...which in this case returns...

```
"58.8235294117647058823529411764705882352941176470588235294117647058823529411764705882352941176470588235"
```

Note in this case, 102 digits of precision are returned rather than 100 because of the relative size of the dividend (1000) to the divisor (17).

Answer (score 0):

I am not a **JAVASCRIPT** coder so I stick with **C++** ...

Converting number to string in **decadic base** is more complicated then using binary or its powers bases (bin,oct,hex) due to fact that all the numbers on usual computer are stored in binary not in decadic. Also it is not the same if you converting integer or fractional part. Let assume we have number `x` and want string `s` encoded in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com) so this is how basic conversion work:

1. **Handle `sign`**

   ```
   s="+";
   if (x<0.0)  { x=-x; s="-"; }
   ```

   as you can see its easy. Some number formats have a separate sign bit (usually the msb one) so in such case the code can be converted to bit operations for example 32 bit `float`:

   ```
   DWORD* dw=(DWORD*)(&x); // allow bit manipulation
   s="+";
   s[0]+=(((*dw)>>30)&2);  // ASCII +,- codes are 2 apart
   (*dw)&=0x7FFFFFFF;      // x=abs(x)
   ```

   so we have extracted sign character for our string and make `x` unsigned.
2. **Handle Integer part of `x`**

   integer is converted to string by **dividing** it by the printing base so:

   ```
   y=floor(x); // integer part
   if (y)
    for (;y;) // until number is nonzero
    {
    s+='0'+(y%10); // works only for up to 10 base
    y/=10;
    }
   else s+='0'; // handle y=0 separately
   ```

   so the remainder of each division is the wanted digit of the string but in reverse order. So after the conversion reverse the digits in string by a single for loop or you can store the number digits in reverse order directly. But for tat you need to know the number of digits of the integer part of the number. That is done by

   ```
   digits = ceil(log(y)/log(base)) + 1
   ```

   so for decadic:

   ```
   digits = ceil(log10(y)) + 1
   ```
3. **handle fractional part of `x`**

   this is converted by **multiplying** by the conversion base.

   ```
   z=x-floor(x); // fractional part
   if (z)
    for (s+='.';z;) // until number is nonzero here you can limit to number of digits
    {
    z*=10.0;
    s+='0'+int(floor(z)); // works only for up to 10 base
    z-=floor(z);
    }
   ```

   this is returning the digits in their order so no reversing this time...

I encoded all the code directly in the SO editor so there might be hidden syntax errors.

Now usual print functions have also formatting which adds zero or space padding or cut off fractional digits above some value etc ...

If you have a bignum `x` then this will be much much slower because you can not handle basic `+,-,*,/` operations as `O(1)` anymore and its usually faster to create `hex` string and convert the string to decadic on 8bit arithmetics instead or use biggest power of 10 that fits into used DATA WORD the bignum is stored with. The `hex -> dec` conversion can be done like this:

- [string hex2dec conversion on integer math](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18231860/2521214)

but again for very big strings it will be slow. In such case it can be speed up by using **FFT/NTT** approaches similar to **Schönhage-Strassen multiplication** but I never tried to use it for printing before so I lack any insights on such approach.

Also beware that determining the number of digits of a value is not regular for fractional part of number (see the link above) so you need to mind that you can be off by `1-2` digits.

**[Edit1] rounding the string**

simply if you detect `n` consequent zeros or nines in the fractional part (after any nonzero digit) you need to stop printing and round. Zeros are just cut of and nines you need to cut off too and increment the rest by one in the string. Such operation might overflow to 1 digit not present in the string so in such case just insert `1`.

When I put all together I come up with this **C++/VCL** code (based on **VCL** `AnsiString` data type):

```cpp
AnsiString print(double x)
    {
    char c;
    int i,j;
    double y,a;
    AnsiString s;

    const int B=10;                 // chose base 2...16
    const double b=B;               // base
    const double _b=1.0/b;          // 1/base
    const char digit[16]="0123456789ABCDEF";

    #define _enable_rounding

    #ifdef _enable_rounding
    const int round_digits=5;       // min consequent 0s or B-1s to triger rounding
    int cnt0=0,cnt1=0;              // consequent digit counters
    int ena=0;                      // enabled consequent digit counters? after first nonzero digit
    #endif

    // here you should handle NaN and Inf cases

    // handle sign
    s="+";
    if (x<0.0)  { x=-x; s="-"; }
    // integer part
    y=floor(x);
    if (y) for (;y>0.0;)        // until number is nonzero
        {
        a=y; y=floor(y*_b);     // the same as y/=10 on integers
        a-=y*b;                 // the same as a=y%10 on integers
        i=int(a);
        s+=digit[i];
        #ifdef _enable_rounding
        ena|=i;
        #endif
        }
    else s+='0';                // handle y=0 separately
    // reverse string skipping +/- sign (beware AnsiString is indexed from 1 up to its length included!!!)
    for (i=2,j=s.Length();i<j;i++,j--){ c=s[i]; s[i]=s[j]; s[j]=c; }
    // fractional part
    y=x-floor(x);
    if (y) for (s+='.';y>0.0;)      // until number is nonzero here you can limit to number of digits
        {
        y*=b;
        a=floor(y);
        y-=a;
        i=int(a);
        s+=digit[i];
        #ifdef _enable_rounding
        ena|=i;
        // detect consequent rounding digits
        if (ena)
            {
                 if (i==  0){ cnt0++; cnt1=0; }
            else if (i==B-1){ cnt1++; cnt0=0; }
            else            { cnt0=0; cnt1=0; }
            }
        // round down .???00000000 by cut of zeros
        if (cnt0>=round_digits)
            {
            s=s.SubString(1,s.Length()-cnt0);       // by cut of zeros
            break;
            }
        // round up .???999999999 by increment and cut of zeros (only base 10) !!!
        if (cnt1>=round_digits)
            {
            s=s.SubString(1,s.Length()-cnt1);       // cut off nines
            for (j=1,i=s.Length();(i>=2)&&(j);i--)
                {
                c=s[i];
                if (c=='.') continue;
                if (c=='9'){ s[i]='0'; continue; }
                j=0; s[i]++;
                }
            if (j) s=s.Insert("1",i+1); // overflow -> insert "1" after sign
            if (s[s.Length()]=='.')     // cut off decimal point if no fractional part left
             s=s.SubString(1,s.Length()-1);
            break;
            }
        #endif
        }
    return s;
    }
```

You can select base `B=<2,16>`. You can enable disable the rounding by using/commenting the `#define _enable_rounding`. Beware the rounding routine works only for base `10` as for different bases the increment routine would have a bit different code/constants and too lazy to do it universally (it would be longer and less comprehend-able code). The `round_digits` constant is a threshold of how many consequent zeros or nines are triggering the rounding.

Comment: If I'm following your explanation correctly, won't it have the same flaw as in my example? The problem of floating point arithmetic, where 0.33-0.03=0.3000000004

Comment: or in your case 3.3 - 3=0.2999999999999

Comment: @Karamell yes  as 0.3 is not representable by a fractional part in binary ... however you can round up the resulting string  while formating the result or even detect a overflow/underflow like patterns: [How to deal with overflow and underflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33006665/2521214). So if your problem is the rounding you should mention it in you question I see nothing about it in there.... The usual rounding scheme is to compare the remainder after the conversion to a limited number of fractional digits with `0.5` or to detect the `9999` pattern in the end of the string ...

Comment: Yes, my question is about not losing precision in the decimal representation, that's why I introduced my question by showing my attempt that didn't accurately stringify the number. I'm not sure I understand how we can accurately know that there's an error by detecting `99999` since that could have been in the number in the first place

Comment: @Karamell You are not loosing precision by the print ... you lost it long before that as 0.3 is not representable by sum of power of 2 numbers/weights so the number you are printing really is `0.29999999... ` the rounding is simple if last digits are `9`s (except few last digits which might be bigger) increment the whole string by 1 and the place of last `9`  and cut of the resulting zeros. This must be done on string no more floating points...

Comment: @Karamell Had some time/mood for this so I added a working C++ print example I busted for your. you see Edit1