# Floating point dramatic error (fractional part is completely lost)

Tags: c#, precision, floating-accuracy

```
quotient = 43156414f / 3;
```

I got `quotient` == 1438547**2** here (totally not as true value should be: 1438547**1,333...**). It completely lost all fractional part!

I know about floating point calculations inacuracy (it seems, not all, that I should to know), but, as I informed, the error could appear at much farther significant digits. But the dividend here is only 8-digits number. Why so dramatic error happens?

*Optional sub-question*: What rules should I keep in mind to foresee such errors in future?

*Just to note*: Changing type of divident from float to double fixes this problem.

Comment: use decimal type, it can hold bigger values than float and don't lose presicion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[float](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) has a precision of 6-9 digits. Your value is just too large to fit into a float without loss.

double has a precision of about 15-17 digits.

As an illustration, inspect the value of `(int)43156414f` or `(double)43156414f` - they are both 4315641*6*

Comment: For some reason there was _"something like 12 digits percision"_ in my head. Apparently, I messed up something. Thank you!

Comment: [It does not make any sense to describe `float` precision as 6-9 digits.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61614323/298225)

Answer (score 3):

Well, `float` (`Single`) uses **23** bits for mantissa

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

So `float` can represent integers up to `2**24 - 1 == 16777215` which is *close* to `14385471`.
The possibilities we have are:

```
 01001011 01011011 10000001 00111111 correponds to 14385471f (let's add 1 bit)
 01001011 01011011 10000001 01000000 correponds to 14385472f
```

So as we can see we have only `14385471f` and `14385472f` to choose from; no place for `14385471.33333f` in case of `floate`.
Let's have a look

```
 float x = 14385471.3333333333f;

 byte[] data = BitConverter.GetBytes(x);

 Console.Write(" ", string.Join(" ", data
   .Reverse()
   .Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'))));
```

We'll have

```
 01001011 01011011 10000001 00111111
```

which corresponds to `14385471f`. Even more problems we have with

```
 quotient = 43156414f / 3;
```

Now, `43156414f > 2**24 - 1 (16777215)` and `43156414f` can't be represented as `float` but

```
 01001100 00100100 10100000 11110000 corresponds to 43156416
```

So the actual value of `quotient` is

```
 43156416 / 3 == 14385472
```

Finally, if you want to have `14385471.33`, `Single` is not enough, try `double`:

```
 // 14385471.333333334
 double quotient = 43156414d / 3;
```