# Precision of single precision floating point numbers (IEEE 754 standard)

Tags: floating-point, binary, precision, ieee-754

In the single precision floating point representation of numbers according to IEEE 754 standard, we use 24 bits for mantissa part (23 bits + 1 implied bit). So the precision can be calculated as 2^24 = 10^x where x can be calculated by taking log on both sides as 24*log 2 = x*log 10 => x= 7.2 ~ 7. From this we can conclude that precision is 7 in decimal system but the value 7 tells that we have 7 significant decimal places of precision or we have 7 decimal digits of precision? Is it considered to be 7 decimal digits (in total) or upto 7 decimal places of precision for decimal numbers.

Comment: [It is not good to think of binary floating-point formats in decimal terms.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61614323/298225) Before you can conclude “the precision is 7,” you would have to define what “the precision” means. There are different ways of defining precision. The IEEE-754 “single” format is sufficiently precise that when any **six**-digit decimal floating-point number within range is converted to the binary floating-point format and back to a six-digit decimal floating-point number, the result equals the starting number. There are seven-digit numbers for which this is not true.

Comment: The IEEE-754 “single” format certainly does not guarantee seven decimal places of precision, meaning seven digits after the decimal point. For numbers above 2^24, only integers are representable; the IEEE-754 “single” values do not have any digits after the decimal point at all.

Answer (score 3):

> precision can be calculated as 2^24 = 10^x ...

> From this we can conclude that precision is 7 in decimal system but the value 7 tells that we have 7 significant decimal places of precision or we have 7 decimal digits of precision?

> Is it considered to be 7 decimal digits (in total) or upto 7 decimal places of precision for decimal numbers.

No.

7 may work as a *rough* approximation of precision<sup>*1</sup>, yet floating point numbers are not quite distributed in a uniform logarithm fashion so “by taking log” fails.

---

For typical [float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), there are 2<sup>23</sup> or 8,388,608 values, *linearly* distributed in the range [1.0 … 2.0).  Likewise for ranges [0.125 … 0.5), [128.0 … 256.0), …

With text as a decimal with precision of 7, there are 9*10<sup>6</sup> or 9,000,000 values *linearly* distributed in the range [1.0 … 10.0) and in other decades.

The problem is these ranges do not always line up to distinguish 7 significant decimal places.

Consider `8589952000.0f`.  The next `float` is 1024.0 away, yet the next 7 significant decimal is 1000.0 away.  After 125 steps to the next `float`, the value is `8590080000.0f`.  But that was 128 steps of 1000.0.  Some  7 significant decimals in that range were not distinctively representable as a `float`.

Some `float` have less than 7 significant decimals of distinctiveness.

Use `floor((24-1) * log10(2))` --> 6 to determine a common `float` worst-case decimal precision or for `float`s in *general*, use `FLT_DIG`.

---

<sup>*1</sup> `log10(pow(2,23))` --> 6.9... is a better approximation.