# Quick way to figure out 32-bit floating point representation and associated loss

Tags: floating-point, precision

I am dealing with real numbers from a given range (namely lontitudes and lagitudes) from a high-precision system which will give me many decimals (in the order of 15 usually, plus of course up to three digits left of the comma). Now, how much these decimals represent actual knowledge I do not know, but I want to use them all.

Question is, for any given number, how to quickly know if 32-bit floating-point representation will incur any loss in decimal places, and if yes, how much ? Is there some online tool to do that, or some quick calculation I can do in an excel sheet or something ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Precision of single precision floating point numbers (IEEE 754 standard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68606110/precision-of-single-precision-floating-point-numbers-ieee-754-standard)

Comment: Actually yes. It has a footnote with a neat little formula : `num_decimals_representable = log10(2^(num_bits_for_mantissa)` And for standard floats we have 21 bits for the mantissa nad so 6.3... decimals representable : not enough for me then !

Answer (score 0):

The worst case binary loss is about the difference in the precision of `float64` and `float32`.  Typically 29 bits.  The decimal loss is then about 29 * log10(2) or 8.7 decimal digits loss.

---

For particular values, some `float32` convert *exactly* into `float64`.

Rather than try to find the *decimal* loss, let us look at the *binary* loss as common [`float32`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) and [`float64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) employ a *binary* floating point encoding.

As with this case of angles, *range* is not much of an issue, consider extracting the significand of the `float64` and assess its least significant bits as compared to the retained bits.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

#define DBL_FLT_DIG_DIFF (DBL_MANT_DIG - FLT_MANT_DIG)
#define DBL_FLT_DIG_DIFF_MOD (1ull << DBL_FLT_DIG_DIFF)

// Return loss in fraciton of a ULB of x as a float.
double double_to_float_loss(double x) {
  if (x < 0) {
    return double_to_float_loss(-x);
  const double scale = DBL_FLT_DIG_DIFF_MOD;
  // The frexp functions break a floating-point number into a normalized
  // fraction and an integer exponent
  int expo;
  long long ifraction = (long long) (frexp(x, &expo) * scale);
  long long loss = ifraction % DBL_FLT_DIG_DIFF_MOD;
  ifraction /= DBL_FLT_DIG_DIFF_MOD;
  // 0.5 as conversion from float64 to float32 typically rounds to nearest.
  return 0.5 * loss/ifraction;
}
```

---

> loss in decimal places,

Easy as for a given `float64`, just assess the number of decimal places in `loss` from above.

```
...
long long loss = ifraction % DBL_FLT_DIG_DIFF_MOD;
int deimcal_loss = 0;
while (loss) {
  loss /= 10;
  decimal_loss++;
}
```

Worse case: `log10(DBL_FLT_DIG_DIFF_MOD)`