# Convert double to float goes wrong - C#

Tags: c#, casting, floating-point, precision

I need to calculate bounds for
`rectangleF` type

For some reason the casting from `double` to `float` is not evaluated precisely as it should be

This is an example of such calculate

```
float MinX = 0f, MaxX = 0f;
float MinY = 0f, MaxY = 0f;
float BoundsWidth = 0.2f;
float BoundsHeight = 0.1f;
double BoundsY = 2333638.6551984739;
double BoundsX = 895.0999755859375;

MinX = (float)BoundsX;
MinY = (float)BoundsY;

var MaxX_Defect = BoundsX + BoundsWidth;
var MaxY_Defect = BoundsY + BoundsHeight;
MaxX = (float)(MaxX_Defect);
MaxY = (float)(MaxY_Defect);
```

When I'm trying to calculate the hight
`MaxY-MinY` its evaluated as `0` instead of `0.1f`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried TryParse?

Comment: `float` does not have enough precision. You can try this: `float a = 2333638; float b = a + 0.1f; Console.WriteLine(b - a);`, it will output 0.

Comment: By converting a `double` to a `float` you're downgrading precision

Comment: [floating point numbers have limited precision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types). simple as that.

Comment: You can use `double` for all those calculations to get more precision, but `double` is also limited in precision so if you have large enough numbers in a `double` you will get the same problem there. Specifically, if you do my `b-a` example in my other comment but switch to `double` you will need to use a number like `2333638000000000` to have the same issue.

Comment: From what I read at the documentation before I didn't over the limit of float, and the precision need to get up to 9 digits.. so I'm confused a little bit @Franz Gleichmann

Comment: I don't care to use double at this calculation but as I wrote, I need it for a ```rectangleF``` type @Lasse V.Karlsen

Comment: I understand that, but `float` will still have limited precision, regardless of what you want. So you need to either accept the problem or deal with it.

Comment: @tamir1020 the point is: do not _ever_ expect floating point numbers to be _precise_ at all. they're just approximations. if you need arbitrary, decimal precision, use `Decimal` instead. (also: i suggest stepping through your code with the debugger and looking at your values. `MinY` gets rounded up to `2333638.75` - because of the limited precision. which is _precisely_ the root of your problem.)

Comment: Ok I find a way through it, tnx

Comment: Re “From what I read at the documentation”: [Unfortunately, Microsoft’s documentation about `float` precision is nonsensical and wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61614323/298225) The `float` type does not guarantee you 9 digits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, your "Unfortunately ..." answer is perhaps one of the best I've read about float accuracy and resolution. By the way, shouldn't this question be closed on the grounds it's a duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @Arc: When people have specific issues, I avoid marking questions as duplicates of that one because it’s overall message is to avoid floating-point, or, if you use it, to regard it as mysterious or unreliable. A better course is to educate people. Ultimately, we ought to have a variety of questions that illuminate floating-point arithmetic, but it is difficult to build that from random questions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I understand, I don't see it diminishing of floats exactly like you do, but I don't think its contents are very enlightening either. As of today, it is the big bucket where about a third of the `precision` tagged questions on float arithmetic go to die. But you are right, tailored answers with specific numerics like the one you provided here - and in many other cases - have far more value in terms of creating knowledge than just closing someone's issue and pointing to work already done.

Comment: Your answer is nearly perfect, I would just suggest you link some references to it, like "What every computer scientist should know..." or perhaps Kunth's chapter 3 of TAOCP, so people are encouraged to seek and read more about floats.

Answer (score 1):

The line `float BoundsHeight = 0.1f;` converts .1 to the nearest value representable in `float`, resulting in `BoundsHeight` being 0.100000001490116119384765625

The line `double BoundsY = 2,333,638.6551984739;` similarly converts to `double`, setting `BoundsY` to 2,333,638.6551984739489853382110595703125.

The line `float MinY = BoundsY;` converts that to `float`, setting `MinY` to 2,333,638.75.

The line `double MaxY_Defect = BoundsY + BoundsHeight;` computes using `double` (I presume; I am not familiar with C# semantics), setting `MaxY_Defect` to 2,333,638.7551984754391014575958251953125.

The line `float MaxY = (float)(MaxY_Defect);` converts that to `float`, setting `MaxY` to 2,333,638.75.

Then we can see that `MinY` and `MaxY` have the same value, so of course `MaxY-MinY` is zero.

Quite simply, `float` does not have enough precision to distinguish between 2,333,638.6551984739489853382110595703125 and 2,333,638.7551984754391014575958251953125. At the scale of 2,333,638, the distance between adjacent representable numbers in the `float` format is .25. This is because the format has 24 bits for the significand (the fraction portion of the floating-point representation). 2,333,638 is between 2<sup>21</sup> and 2<sup>22</sup>, so the exponent in its floating-point representation scales the significand to have bits representing values from 2<sup>21</sup> to 2<sup>−2</sup> (from 21 to −2, inclusive, is 24 positions). So changing the significand by 1 in its lowest bit changes the represented number by 2<sup>−2</sup> = .25.

Thus, when 2,333,638.655… and 2,333,638.755… are converted to `float`, they have the same result, 2,333,638.75.

You cannot use `float` to distinguish between coordinates or sizes that are this close at that magnitude. You can use `double` or you might be able to translate the coordinates to be nearer the origin (so their magnitudes are smaller, putting them in a region where the `float` resolution is finer).

As long as the final result is small, you could do the intermediate calculations using `double` but still represent the final result well using `float`.

For additional information on floating-point arithmetic, I recommend [*Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic* by Muller, Brunie, de Dinechin, Jeannerod, Joldes, Lefèvre, Melquiond, Revol, and Torres](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319765256). A PDF of a prior edition appears to be available [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/47735229_Handbook_of_Floating-Point_Arithmetic). The official IEEE 754-2019 Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic is available [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8766229).