# float division in C for large numbers

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, division

The same operations seem to work differently for larger and smaller values (I think the code below explains the question better than I could in words) I have calculated max and max3 in the same way except the values are different. Similarly I have calculated max2 and max4 the exact same way with different values. Yet the answer I'm getting is very different?:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    // 86997171 / 48 = 1812441.0625
    int max = ceil((float) 86997171 / 48);
    float max2 = ((float) 86997171)/ 48;
    printf("max = %i, max2 = %f\n", max, max2);
    int max3 = ceil((float) 3 / 2);
    float max4 = ((float) 3) / 2;
    printf("ma3 = %i, max4 = %f\n", max3, max4);
}
```

Output:

```
max = 1812441, max2 = 1812441.000000
ma3 = 2, max4 = 1.500000
```

I was expecting max = 1812442, max2 = 1812441.062500 to be the output, since that's what it should be in principle. Now I don't know what to do

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250508/discussion-on-question-by-rubyshanks-float-division-in-c-for-large-numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, `float` is a [single-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), so it is usually 4 bytes (on most compilers), so its precision is around 6-9 significant digits, typically 7 digits.

Your number in question, `1812441.0625` has 11 digits, which don't fit in a `float` type.

You should use `double` instead, which in C is a [double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), so it is usually 8 bytes (on most compilers) so its precision is around 15-18 significant digits, typically 16 digits, and therefore can keep the precision of your number.

In fact, using `double` in this case gives:

```
max = 1812442, max2 = 1812441.062500
ma3 = 2, max4 = 1.500000
```

which is what you need.

[Link to code](https://godbolt.org/z/rKx91fejc).

---

Note that the precision of these types is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61614323/14193797). It is far from the truth (as explained by the link), but it gives good perspective in your question.

Comment: Saying `float` has “6-9 significant digits” is [nonsensical and wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61614323/298225).

Answer (score 2):

> float division in C for large numbers

This issue has nothing to do with division. The rounding error occurs in the initial conversion to `float`.

In the format most commonly used for `float`, IEEE-754 binary32, the two representable numbers closed to 86,997,171 are 86,997,168 and 86,997,176. (These are 10,874,746•2<sup>3</sup> and 10,874,747•10<sup>3</sup>. 10,874,746 and 10,874,747 are 24-bit numbers (it takes 24 digits in binary to represent them), and 24 bits is all the binary32 format has for representing the fraction portion of a floating-point number.)

Of those two, 86,997,168 is closer. So, in `(float) 86997171`, 86,997,171 is converted to 86,997,168.

Then 86,997,168 / 48 is 1,812,441. So `(float) 86997171 / 48` is 1,812,441, and so is `ceil((float) 86997171 / 48)`. So `max` and `max2` are both set to 1,812,441.