# Homemade 'fabs' function in C and x86 Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, floating-point, constants

I'm trying to make in GNU C an fabs function that returns the absolute value of a 32 bits float. I have three different ways, called fabs1, fabs2, and fabs3:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union
{
    float v;
    struct
    {
        int mantissa : 23;
        int exponent : 8;
        int negative : 1;
    } b;
} components;

float fabs1(float f)
{
    return f >= 0.0 ? f : -f;
}

float fabs2(float f)
{
    components c;

    c.v = f;
    c.b.negative = 0;

    return c.v;
}

float fabs3(float f)
{
    double aux = f;
    unsigned short cw;

    __asm__
    (
        "finit;\
        fstcw %[cw];\
        andw $0xf0ff, %[cw];\
        orw $0x0200, %[cw];\
        fldcw %[cw];\
        fldl %[aux];\
        fabs;\
        fstpl %[aux];"
        : [aux] "=mr" (aux) : "m" (aux), [cw] "m" (cw)
    );

    return aux;
}

void main(void)
{
    printf("fabs(-189.55f) = %f\n", fabs(-189.55f));

    printf("fabs1(-189.55f) = %f\n", fabs1(-189.55f));
    printf("fabs2(-189.55f) = %f\n", fabs2(-189.55f));
    printf("fabs3(-189.55f) = %f\n", fabs3(-189.55f));
}
```

There are three different functions, one using a simple decision, one a bit more complicated using unions, and a final one using x86 assembly. I am compiling it in Cygwin 32 bits with:

```
C:/Developer/Cygwin/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -masm=att -I.. -std=c99 -o main.exe main.c
```

I'm running it in Windows 11 and the results are:

```
fabs(-189.55f) = 189.550000
fabs1(-189.55f) = 189.550003
fabs2(-189.55f) = 189.550003
fabs3(-189.55f) = 189.550003
```

But they should really be:

```
fabs(-189.55f) = 189.550000
fabs1(-189.55f) = 189.550000
fabs2(-189.55f) = 189.550000
fabs3(-189.55f) = 189.550000
```

Can you spot the difference? How do I get rid of the extra 0.000003 in all three cases?

Comment: Can you explain what "It works fine in 64 bits, but not in 32 bits" really means? Error? Incorrect result? Give us the details.

Comment: ia64 refers to [Itanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium) which I suspect is not what you have.  The common 64-bit desktop architecture is called x86-64 or amd64 (or x64 by Microsoft).  But since you're compiling as 32-bit code, you're not using that either; this is just x86.

Comment: Keep in mind that `-189.55` is not a value that can be exactly represented in binary floating point.  The nearest representable value for `float`, I believe, is `-189.5500030517578125`.

Comment: I think the `fabs` version might be able to promote the value directly to `double`, since `fabs` is defined with a `double` argument and return value, and then you get the nearest `double` to `-189.55` which is much closer.  I'd have to double check C's rules for floating point literals.  I suspect if you use `fabsf` instead you will get the same result as the other versions.

Comment: Do read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken if you haven't done so lately.

Comment: You didn't say what the problem is.

Comment: What are the results in 32-bits where it didn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure why you mess with the rounding mode.  `fabs` toggles the sign bit, it should not cause rounding.

Comment: Look at the generated code. For example I wonder whether on the 32-bit platform, the compiler effectively treats `fabs(189.55f)`  as `fabs(189.55)`. It is best to use the function `fabsf()` when performing `float` computation. FWIW, `fabs1()` is incorrect. IEEE-754 defines absolute value as a non-arithmetic bit-level operation. If you do an exhaustive test I think you will find that that it fails for negative zero and NaNs with the sign bit set.

Comment: In your bitfield version, the mantissa field would normally be `unsigned`.  And the exponent field is only 2's complement after unbiasing, so probably best to use `unsigned int` as the base type for your bitfields.

Comment: Based on thirty years of experience programming in C I would recommend to *never* use bitfields. Use masks and logic operations on unsigned integers for bit manipulation.

Comment: Interesting; https://godbolt.org/z/W7vzPn1rd shows `-O2 -std=c99` vs. `-O2 -std=gnu99` is what makes the difference between `189.550000` and `189.550003` in 32-bit mode.  The C99 version is passing a `double` constant to printf (after constant propagation through `double fabs(double)`), but the GNU99 version is respecting the `f` suffix on the constant and actually converting a float `189.55f` to `double`.  (@NateEldredge).  So it has the same rounding error as the versions that actually do stuff with a `float` value, including `fabs3` where const-prop doesn't work through inline asm.

Comment: I'd have expected the GNU99 version to be "sloppier". (e.g. does C99 enable `-ffloat-store`)? Clang compiles them the same, but it's using SSE math even with `-m32`.  (And doesn't seem to support `-mfpmath=387`, although `-mno-sse` works.)  Older clang seems to be broken on Godbolt (for linking/running), but clang3.3 pointed out the use-uninitialized error in `unsigned short cw;` - the actual bug is that you told the compiler it was an input when it's actually a dummy output (which you write).  You must not write to input-only operands.  Surprised newer compilers didn't complain about that

Comment: Anyway https://godbolt.org/z/eqEe7Ga49 shows clang 16 producing `189.550003`, with a `double` with lots of trailing 0 bits in its mantissa, like it should have after conversion from `float`.  (Same code-gen for that printf(fabs(-189.55f))` with or without optimization, since it's all in one statement.  This *might* be a GCC bug, unless there's something in the standard that gives a compiler the option of treating a `(double)float_literal` as `double` directly, with more precision.

Comment: Anyway, there's an interesting compiler difference here, and the homemade `fabs` implementations are completely irrelevant to an [mcve] of it.  (Except as something the compiler won't constprop through, but a `volatile` variable could do that in a much simpler test case.)  I'd recommend asking a new question about if / why `(double)-189.55f` is allowed to produce a `double` that's not exactly representable as a `float`, instead being more precise and closer in magnitude to the `189.55` part of the literal in the source, ignoring the `f` suffix.

Comment: @Cucom, note that `fabs1(-0.0)` returns -0.0.

Comment: Given that `float` is good for no more than 6 digits of decimal precision, all the answers are valid.  `double` is good for 15 significant figures.  Moreover the `printf` involves a conversion to `double` before presenting the binary floating point value in decimal (a further conversion of representation).  There are many things that could cause these differences in the digits, and not all if them need be in your fabs() implementation.  You would do better to inspect the results in a debugger than to rely on your own code for that.

Comment: @Clifford: Re “Given that `float` is good for no more than 6 digits of decimal precision”: [That is wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61609276/how-to-calculate-float-type-precision-and-does-it-make-sense/61614323#61614323) The numbers represented by a floating-point type are exact, and that is what matters for this issue. Re “all the answers are valid”: That is wrong. The C standard requires floating-point literals of the same form to produce the same value, so the compiler must translate `189.55f` to the same value in each place it appears.

Comment: Re: your update: `189.550003` is the correct answer; `189.55f` is not exactly representable as a `float`, so has to get rounded to a nearby value that a float bit-pattern can represent.  Converting that float back to decimal, it's `189.5500030517578125`.  See it in action with https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html when you enter 189.55, and see the nearest representable `float`.  So other than GCC's weird extra precision, this is pretty much a duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004) (and see Eric's answer in the prev comment).

Comment: @EricPostpischil They are not floating point literals in this case, but return values from the OP's functions.  You have misunderstood my point about 6 significant figures, it would be off topic and take too long to clarify my point here.  As short as possible; when a single precision _binary floating point_ is presented as a decimal _real_, only 6 significant figures will reliably be as they would be had the calculation been performed in decimal.  It is not offered as an _answer_, but merely to point out the flaws in the observation.  Peter Cordes describes the issue in more specifically.

Comment: @Clifford: The OP's return values are correct. None of the OP's functions introduces any extra rounding (`return -f` is precise, and the others are bit-manip or asm), so Eric's point about the FP literal confirms that printing `189.550000` is a GCC bug with `-m32 -std=c17` (as opposed to gnu17, and only with the 32-bit default `-mfpmath=387`): `fabs(-189.55f)` should also produce `189.550003`.  https://godbolt.org/z/n53nsKhW6 simplies the MCVE to just `printf(..., 189.55f)`, showing we get a double who's value isn't representable as a float.  (TODO: report this to GCC's bugzilla.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't say they were not correct.  Quite the opposite.  I was merely pointing out all thay might make the observation unreliable.  Relying on the behaviour of printf being one of my points.  I am less interested in all the language lawyer stuff and more interested in what actually happens with the tools to hand.  Here an erroneous conclusion was drawn by use of a flawed observation.  The six significant digits point was a more general issue that if you are looking for "errors" at a greater _decimal_ precision than that, you will surely find them at some point.

Comment: It was a general comment in what to expect if you look for precision beyond the capability of the representation in a number base different from that of the representation.  Not an answer to the question.  Not all points necessary apply to this specific code.  I may have been somewhat imprecise in my language in an attempt to be brief.

Comment: I see there are some delicate issues here. The lesson, though, seems to be to stick to doubles wherever possible, because they are more precise. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The basic issue causing the `3` to appear is that the number `189.550000` can't be represented to that level of precision in a `float` -- the closest value is `189.5500030517578125` (`0x1.7b199ap+7` in hex), which when printed with 6 digits after the decimal point is `189.550003`

The compiler is permitted to do operations at higher precision, so when you use `fabs` (which may be builtin and returns a `double`), you may get the value `189.55000000000001136868377216160297393798828125` (the closest you can get with double precision -- `0x1.7b1999999999ap+7` in hex), but all your handwritten functions return the float value of `189.5500030517578125`

To get rid of the 3s you can:

- change everything to `double` precision
- change the output to 5 chars after the decimal (`%.5f` in the format)

However, neither fixes the fundamental problem that IEEE binary floating point numbers cannot exactly represent base-10 fractions, so there will always be rounding and imprecision going on.

Comment: Every call to some `fabs` variant in OP’s code passes `-189.55f` as argument. This should always be a `float` of the same value, and the fact one of the calls is to `fabs` and that `fabs` has a `double` parameter and `double` return type should be irrelevant. `-189.55f` should produce a `float` value before it is passed to `fabs`, and passing it to `fabs` should not change that value. Peter Cordes already identified the problem, a compiler defect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The precision of `float` is just a minimum -- the compiler is always permitted to evaluate things at higher precision if it wants to, but it is not required to.  But that is irrelevant to the OPs question of why the `3` appears (and how to get rid of it), which is due to using `float` precision.

Comment: The C standard explicitly states that all instances of a floating-point literal of the same form (exactly the same characters in the source text) must convert to the same value. C 2018 6.4.4.2 5: “… All floating constants of the same source form shall convert to the same internal format with the same value.”

Comment: *The compiler is permitted to do operations at higher precision* - Yes, but `189.55f` means the *starting point* for any operations must still be a `float` that can actually have existed, as Eric says.  That literal has a value of type `float`.  Gaining precision beyond that requires breaking in to the parsing of the `float` and changing to parsing it as a `double`, which as Eric says is not what the standard says should happen.  https://godbolt.org/z/n53nsKhW6 shows that as args to printf, `(float)189.55f` has the expected low zeros in the mantissa but plain `189.55f` doesn't.

Comment: @Eric: Upon checking for existing duplicate bug-reports, https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108742 (*Incorrect constant folding with (or exposed by) -fexcess-precision=standard*) / https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=110476 already exist. GCC's "excuse" for this behaviour is that `FLT_EVAL_METHOD=2` (from `-mfpmath=387`) allows `long double` to replace `float` when parsing  `189.55f`, but `(float)189.55f` rounds (`-std=gnu11` happens to work as we'd expect w. `-fexcess-precision=fast`. `c11` implies `standard` https://godbolt.org/z/35P37hhY9)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Ugh. Lousy excuse. I expect the standard’s reason for allowing excess precision is for run-time performance—use one FMA instead of two instructions, use double-precision instructions on a processor without single-precision instructions, etc. Interpreting the standard’s latitude on computation as applying to translating constants is questionable. I would expect most experienced floating-point programmers to think that `189.55f` refers to a specific value, so the GCC behavior will be surprising to them.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Same.  IDK if we should post on the existing bugs to encourage a change here, since they're about comparison failures (of a variable against a literal), but at least one of them has explicit discussion of a literal having higher precision than it should.  Regardless of whether it can be justified by twisting the language of the standard, I don't think it's *good* behaviour.  If it can easily be changed without breaking anything else in worse ways, it should.