# Precision different while calling from Raku nativecall

Tags: c, raku, rakudo, nativecall

I was looking to write `linspace` function of NumPy.

As the loops are faster in compiled code, tried writing in C and calling from Raku.

```c
//  C code
#include <stdio.h> 
#ifdef _WIN32 
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else 
#define DLLEXPORT extern // if c++ code, requires extern "C"
#endif

DLLEXPORT void c_linspace(double start, double step, int num, double* vals) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    vals[i] = start;
    start += step;
}
}
```

```
// Raku code
sub c_linspace(num64, num64, int32, CArray[num64]) 
    is native( MYDYN) { * };

sub raku_linspace($start, $end, $num, :$endpoint = True, :$retstep = False) {
    my $step = $endpoint ?? ($end - $start)/($num - 1) !!  ($end-$start)/($num);
    my $vals = CArray[num64].allocate($num);
    c_linspace($start.Num, $step.Num, $num.Int, $vals);
    $retstep ?? ($vals.list, $step) !! $vals.list
}
```

Works OK, but checking the precision of the results for example:

Raku gives:

```
say raku_linspace(1,3,300000)[200]   # gives 1.0013333377777869
```

While NumPy gives:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.linspace(1,3,300000)[200]
print(arr) # gives 1.0013333377777927
```

Why this difference in precision? My expectation was `double` was supposed to maintain precision to 15 decimal digits.

The [docs](https://docs.raku.org/language/nativetypes) mention `double` is mapped to `num64`.

Also mentions there are [Rakudo specific types](https://docs.raku.org/language/nativetypes) where `long`, `longlong` is mentioned. So what does `long double` maps to in Raku. It does not appear to be `num64`.

**System information**:
Windows 10 64 bit
gcc 13.2.0

It looks like the problem is directly in C due to floating point errors rather than calling via nativecall. Because running C gives what Raku is giving.

Yet, is there mechanism in nativecall to handle `long double` or `long long` preferably with an example?

Also *what could be done* to make this function with the same precision as NumPy?

Comment: Re “My expectation was `double` was supposed to maintain precision to 15 decimal digits”: This is false. Nothing about `double` “maintains” any accuracy. There is a potential rounding error in each operation performed, and those errors may compound or cancel, effectively randomly. Nothing adjusts those rounding errors to “maintain” any accuracy. You need to understand floating-point arithmetic and expect that rounding errors will occur, and it helps to learn about their nature. When you use different algorithms, you should expect different rounding errors and hence different results.

Comment: Additionally, the format commonly used for `double` does not have any decimal digits at all. It uses a base-two format, and describing it as “15 digits” is a [crude approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61609276/how-to-calculate-float-type-precision-and-does-it-make-sense/61614323#61614323) of the amount of information it carries, not a description of its actual nature.

Comment: This question does not seem to be a Raku-related one. I checked the output of the C function with doubles and long doubles, and the result is 1.0013333377777869 -- which indicates an imprecision OR a different method of calculating `linspace` in numpy.

Comment: "is there mechanism in nativecall to handle `long double`?" Nativecall only *directly* supports [a small list of fixed size C data types](https://docs.raku.org/language/nativetypes#Types_with_native_representation_and_size). Instead you'd need to first *determine the fixed size of `long double` in your situation*. Read your C compiler doc for more info. Then *allocate that amount of storage* (in either C or Raku). Then *write a Raku parameter with a reference to that storage* in your call to the C function that will write to it. Then, in Raku, *cast C's result* into something you can use.

Comment: Yeah, `longlong` is in the document cited by @raiph -- altough shoeing in support for `long double` in `lib/NativeCall.rakumod` in rakudo should not be too complex...

Comment: @raiph Thanks for the information. An illustration/example/blog of that would be a great help. I checked https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/tree/main/lib/NativeCall but not sure how to do about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel No. Yes, it's true that floating point has that aspect. And yes, it's true that in Raku `0.1 + 0.2 = 0.3` is `True` (because Raku treats decimal literals like `0.1` as literally decimals, and thus rationals, not floating point numbers, and thus the expression is exactly true). But both these aspects are unrelated to what @Suman is trying to do, whether or not one sidesteps the XY problem aspect of .@Suman's Q.

Comment: See also also .@Suman's follow up Q [Mapping `long double` in C to Raku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77421633/mapping-long-double-in-c-to-raku.)

Comment: @raiph The OP is invoking C code with a `double`, which it means it's using floating point operations, not decimals.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes. [By the time you commented, "The answer to this question is: numpy's linspace uses a different calculation" had already been accepted. So I presumed you knew that. (You did, right?) I thought you were perhaps referring to .@Suman maybe having been confused due to having had 100% precision via Raku's built in support for rationals, and/or not knowing about float imprecision. But I know (or at least thought) they already knew about it (from prior discussions), and were deliberately sticking with FP to retain its performance and library ubiquity, despite its imprecisions.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if we should un-tag this question, edit it, or another thing, but anyway: this is not a NativeCall question, nor a Raku question, it's a C question, and the "real" question here is:

> Why is my `c_linspace` generating a different result from `numpy.linspace`?

The answer to this question is: `numpy`'s `linspace` uses a different calculation, probably to use SMP instructions. It does (simplifying a bit):

```
    y = _nx.arange(0, num, dtype=dt).reshape((-1,) + (1,) * ndim(delta))
    step = delta / div
    y *= step
    y += start
```

The C equivalent would be:

```
void c_linspace(double start, double step, int num, double* vals) {
  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    vals[i] = (double) i;
  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    vals[i] *= step;
  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    vals[i] += start;
}
```

If you use this implementation, your Raku code will return the same result of `1.0013333377777927` as the `numpy` version.

But, as stated in the comments, even

```
void c_linspace(double start, double step, int num, double* vals) {
  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    vals[i] = i * step + start;
}
```

would suffice...

Answering your other question, i.e.,

> Yet, is there mechanism in nativecall to handle `long double` or `long long` preferably with an example?

`long long` is supported in rakudo, the type is called `longlong` or `ulonglong` in its unsigned variant. The `long double` type is not supported (yet?) but it should be easy (although not trivial) to add support for it in https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/main/lib/NativeCall.rakumod (the not trivial part is to complete the tests etc).

Comment: `vals[i] = start + i * step` with a single loop should suffice i think

Comment: Let's test it... Yes, it does suffice.

Comment: Though I suppose the numpy version is SMD-paralelizable...

Comment: this is SIMDable as well. that NumPy jumps through hoops is because it cares about edge cases

Comment: @MustafaAydın I just checked in CompilerExplorer, the compact version is even better SIMDable than the three-loops one ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Massa. To use it in raku, I need to map `long double` to a **custom datatype** in raku which i have to look at.

Comment: @Suman I tried it here, but it gives me the message that "unsupported num size (128bit)" rs

Comment: @Massa - Given the Raku specific answers to adjacent questions, I think untagging is not necessary, here. There is plenty of useful information for Raku, Python AND C programmers.