# Mapping long double in C to Raku

Tags: c, raku, rakudo, nativecall

Say I have a C function

```c
long double foo(long double *array, size_t n) {

// do something

}
```

How to call this function from Raku?

In [rakudo specific types](https://docs.raku.org/language/nativetypes), there is mention of

| Raku | C type |
| --- | --- |
| long | long in C |
| longlong | longlong in C |
| ulong | long and unsigned in C |
| ulonglong | longlong and unsigned in C |
| size_t | size_t and unsigned in C |
| ssize_t | size_t in C |
| bool | bool in C |

So I thought if `long double` can be mapped as `long num64`, which was not the case.

Comment: I know nothing about Raku but, in most C implementations a plain `double` is a 64-bit IEEE number and `long double` is either a 128-bit IEEE or (as in MSVC) exactly the same as an ordinary `double`.

Comment: It can also be a different size. The IEEE 80-bit floating point type is likely used on some implementations as the Intel FPU uses that type, internally.

Comment: ["In C ... `long double` \[is\] at least as precise as `double`. As with C's other floating-point types, it may not necessarily map to an IEEE format."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double) So `long double` does not have a fixed bit width or fixed format. So for a first step you must determine *exactly* what format any `long double` value *has been compiled down to in a particular C library file*. It will typically be in accord with some IEEE float standard. It will typically be some particular bit width, say, `80` bits. But whatever it is, you *must* know before you can proceed.

Answer (score 2):

The raku design docs ([synopsis](https://design.raku.org/S09.html#PDL_support) 09) call for a num128 type. Afaict this is not yet implemented in rakudo.

The implication is:

1. raku can only handle num64 (double in C)
2. you may need to write a C stub to coerce to from long double

Edit: per the comment, here is a worked example of how to write a stub that coerces double to/from long double (for ubuntu):

First write your stub file and put in eg. sqrt_double.c:

```
#include <math.h>

double sqrt_double(double num) {
    long double num_ld = (long double)num; // Coerce to long double
    long double result_ld = sqrtl(num_ld);  // Calculate square root
    return (double)result_ld;              // Coerce back to double
}
```

Then compile it to a SO:

```
gcc -shared -o libsqrt_double.so -fPIC sqrt_double.c -lm
```

It will appear in a file like 'libsqrt_double.so'

Then write your raku with Nativecall:

```
use NativeCall;

# Define the C library as a Raku module
sub sqrt_double(num64) returns num64 is native('./sqrt_double') {*} 

# Declare a Raku sub to call the C function
sub c_sqrt($value) {
    sqrt_double($value.Num).Num
}

# Call the Raku sub with a double value
my $res = c_sqrt(3.14);

say $res ** 2;    #3.1399999999999997
```

Note that the is native trait will automatically generate the .so filename according to the rules of your OS.

Comment: Looks like there's lot of potential in Raku roadmap. I will wait till the implementation then. In the meantime, are there workarounds e.g. example?