# Minimum number of digits for exact double-precision and the fmt='%.18e' of numpy.savetxt()

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, binary, precision

I want to save 64-bit (double-precision) floating point numbers to a text file in Python using NumPy's [`savetxt()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html). The default format is `fmt='%.18e'` which gives 19 significant decimal digits (e.g. `f'{np.pi:.18e}' == '3.141592653589793116e+00'`). According to e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), however, 64-bit floats only contain 15 to 17 significant decimal digits, 2 lower than the 19 used by default by `savetxt()`.

###### Question

I want to know if I can get by using `savetxt(..., fmt='%.16e')` without any loss of precision, i.e. saving and then loading should be binary compatible with the original data. If so, why is `fmt='%.18e'` the default and not `fmt='%.16e'`?

###### Test code

To test this experimentally, I wrote the following:

```py
import numpy as np
def test(n, iterations=1_000_000, scale=2**20):
    for i in range(iterations):
        a = scale*(np.random.random()*2 - 1)
        for b in [a, np.nextafter(a, -np.inf), np.nextafter(a, np.inf)]:
            if float(f'{{:.{n}e}}'.format(b)) != b:
                return False
    return True
for n in range(19):
    print(f'Binary compatibility with fmt=%.{n}e ({n + 1} significant digits)?', test(n))
```

which indeed gives

```
.
.
.
Binary compatibility with fmt=%.15e (16 significant digits)? False
Binary compatibility with fmt=%.16e (17 significant digits)? True
Binary compatibility with fmt=%.17e (18 significant digits)? True
Binary compatibility with fmt=%.18e (19 significant digits)? True
```

suggesting that 17 significant digits are always enough, i.e. anything beyond `fmt='%.16e'` is wasteful.

###### Edit

From the [CPP reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cfloat), the needed number of significant digits needed is indeed `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG = 17`, corresponding to `fmt='%.16e'`. The question of why [`savetxt()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) chooses `fmt='%.18e'` remains.

Comment: Also, the Wikipedia page does not say 64-bit floats “contain” 15 to 17 significant decimal digits. It says the 53-bit significand precision “gives” from 15 to 17 significant digits, which is better phrasing, but [is still wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61609276/how-to-calculate-float-type-precision-and-does-it-make-sense/61614323#61614323).

Comment: @EricPostpischil As stated in the question `%.16e` in fact results in 17 digits.

Comment: OP followed up this with a question to the [numpy-discussion mailing list](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/numpy-discussion@python.org/thread/DGEYIWDWWR22Q4FIIUIKIWYLFVE2LLSF/)

Comment: Opinion is that the extra digits were due to code that might have "relied on the platform's floating point to string conversion routines, which were of variable quality. The extra digits accounted for that unreliability"