# Why is double printing the same value as float in C when they have different sizes?

Tags: c, floating-point, double

I need to do calculations using π. When I checked precision of M_PI, it only printed 7 decimal digits. So I `#defined` my own `MY_PI`. But I am still facing the same problem. `double` should support 15-17 decimal digits. Why am I only getting 6

```
#define MY_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%f\n%lf\n%20lf\n",M_PI,M_PI,M_PI);
    printf("%d\n%d\n",sizeof(float),sizeof(double));
    printf("%f\n%lf\n%20lf\n",MY_PI,MY_PI,MY_PI);
    return 0;
}
```

Executing the code results in this,

```
3.141593
3.141593
            3.141593
4
8
3.141593
3.141593
            3.141593

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.080 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: @Lundin the code does work.

Comment: For vararg functions like `printf`, all `float` values are *promoted* to `double`. Therefore `%f` and `%lf` are exactly the same.

Comment: @Dario.Casciato Not in my standard C compiler (gcc). Maybe you are using some non-standard extension which defines `M_PI`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The code has both `MY_PI` and `M_PI`.

Comment: Also note that `MY_PI` will be expanded to a `double` value. So you're really printing the same value using the same (essentially) format. If you store the value in a `float` variable, and print that variable, the result will likely be different.

Comment: And finally, I suspect you mean to use e.g. `%.20f` instead of `%20f`?

Comment: To clarify, this will only work with non-standard extensions such as `gcc -std=gnu23 -lm`. Not with standard C `gcc -std=c23 -pedantic-errors -lm`. There's nothing called `M_PI` in standard C.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Yes, I did, that does show full length of digits. thanks

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  But, I still don't understand why double is only showing 6 decimal places?

Comment: i used the onlinegdb C compiler and the code worked for me

Comment: Because without any length modifier, the `%f` format is specified to default to 6 digits precision. In other words, `%f` is the same as `%.6f`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  What is the default precision of double for mathematical calculations?

Comment: The default is for printing, not for calculations. Calculations are done to the maximum precision.

Comment: @Dario.Casciato That's a GNU compiler or maybe a C++ compiler even. Use a C compiler. gcc is not unless you tell it to become one, `-std=c17 -pedantic`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Re “Oh and by the way, a double-precision IEEE 754 number will have only 15 (and a bit more, but not 16) decimal digits.”: [That is not a correct statement.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61614323/298225)

Comment: @Lundin That "non-standard extension which defines `M_PI`" is probably the X/Open CAE specification, or possibly one of the earlier X/Open Portability Guides, i.e. Unix standardization stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C does not pass type information about arguments to a function. `printf` takes all type information from the format string you pass it.

For historical reasons, both `%f` and `%lf` tell `printf` to expect a `double` argument. Per C 2018 7.21.6.1 8, `%f` instructs `printf`:

> A `double` argument representing a floating-point number is converted to decimal notation in the style *[-]ddd.ddd*, where the number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification. If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6;…

Thus six digits are printed merely because that is the default, not because of anything particularly to do with the type. To see more digits, request more digits:

```
printf("%.60f\n", M_PI);
```

This will commonly print:

```
3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875000000000000
```

Note that `%20f` requests a *field width* of 20 characters. A field width is typically used for spacing, to help align columns of data over multiple lines. To satisfy a field width, spaces are used for padding. The code above uses `%.60f` to request *precision*, which controls the number of digits produced.

Answer (score 3):

- Everything passed to variadic functions like `printf` undergoes implicit argument promotion. In case of `float`, it always gets promoted to `double`. So `%f` and `%lf` means the same thing. There are only two different versions available to make `printf` consistent with `scanf` where `%f` vs `%lf` matters.
- `printf` caps the amount of decimals to 6 (and rounds the value) unless you tell it otherwise.
- `%20lf` only tells how many characters to print (for purposes of alignment/padding with spaces etc). To tell it how many *decimals* to print, use
  `%.20lf` with a `.`. Or if you will a combination, `%20.20lf`.
- `1415926535897932384626433832795028841971` is of type `double` or `long double`. Casting it to `float` before passing it to `printf` will result in the expected loss of precision.

---

Example (GNU C `gcc -lm`):

```
  printf("%.20lf\n%.20lf\n",M_PI, (float)M_PI);
```

Output:

```
  3.14159265358979311600
  3.14159274101257324219
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the precision of printf you are giving it. when using %f or %lf, the printf function always prints only 6 digits after the decimal. You have to tell it how many digits after the decimal you want. It looks like you tried this, but not the right way. you have to add a dot before the number of digits you want to see.

example:

```
printf("Test: %.20lf", MY_PI);
```