# Are JavaScript built in objects defined in source files and then compiled?

Tags: javascript, object

Are built in objects in JavaScript like Math, Array, String etc... just defined in a .js file and then compiled and or interpreted? Can I get a basic high level overview of how they are implemented and made available?  I see that in Java there is a String class and that class gets compiled and is available when I need to create an object, is JavaScript similar?

Thank You.

Comment: No, they're defined in the engine, and engines aren't written in Javascript, they're written in C, C++, maybe other languages. That's why you see things like `[native code]`

Comment: [How to see the source of Built-in javascript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300206) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/22300206?sort=votes

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks.  I'm assuming built in objects in Java are compiled class files then?  Is that correct?  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Java