# How does dot notion work in array or different places

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to understand dot notion and how can we create dot notion

Simply state, consider this example

```
const a = [1,2,3,4,5,7].reduce((a, i) => a*i)
```

Here how can we use `dot` notion.

From my understanding, we use dot notion in case of object.

probably `Array` have a prototype named `reduce`? and `reduce` accepts 4 arguments.

But how do we tell reduce to iterate over the loop. We aren't passing it the entire array?

Comment: whta do you mean with *"dot"*?

Comment: @NinaScholz `.`  `.map` or `.reduce` (just the dot). like using `.lowerCase()`, `.toString`

Comment: you are using it as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: @NinaScholz right. then in case of **Arrays** , when we used `.map` or `.forEach` or in case of `string`, when we use `.toLowerCase()`, how does it knows that we need to iterate (in case of array)? like we aren't passing array to function arguments?

Comment: please have a look to the link.

Answer (score 1):

When we add any method to `prototype` of the class we can always access the instance of the class on which this method is called by `this`.

```js
Array.prototype.test = function(){
  console.log(this);
};
[1,2,3].test()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reduce function is a built in javascript function which works only with arrays.

You don't tell explicitly to 'reduce' to iterate all over the array because it(reduce function) is already coded such that it does something(add, sum, multiply, whatever expression you may provide) with that array.

If you really want to know what is going on the background, you can see this torque file which is from V8 engine's source code==>https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/builtins/array-reduce.tq

From what I understood, it also uses a for loop inside the function.

For that you should also have understanding of TorqueScript.

You can check any open source engine for that matter.For more details about how to view the code and where exactly, visit this link==>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300206/how-to-see-the-source-of-built-in-javascript-functions

So to answer your question => it simply just calls reduce and rest of the work is taken care by it in the background, that's not really associated with 'dot notion'.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are special objects. But the usability of dot notation doesn't depend on the object, but rather the property you want to access.

Also note that `foo.bar` is the same as `foo['bar']`.

You can **always** use bracket notation. On the other hand, dot notation can only be used if the property **is a valid identifier** (consists of letters, numbers, `$`s and `_`s, and can't begin with a number).

That shows the reason why we can't access arrays' indices with it, as they are numbers (so they also *begin with* numbers).

The bracket notation is also required if you want to access a key named the result of evaluating an expression.

So:

```
const object = {
  0: 1,
  foo: 2,
  'key with spaces': 3,
  '3D': 4,
  'D3': 5
}
const array = [1, 2, 3]

//These are okay...
object.foo
object['foo']
array.reduce
array['reduce']
object[0]
array[0]
object['0']
array['0']
object['key with spaces']
object['3D']
object.D3
object['D3']
object['f' + 'o'.repeat(2)]
array[array.length-2]

//...but these are not:

object.0
array.0
object.key with spaces
object.3D //begins with a number
```